# Jacoco code coverage with Sonar and maven for integration tests in separate module

Tags: maven, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I've configured my project with SonarQube and Jacoco for code coverage. Everything works well except one thing. I divided project in many maven sub modules:

```
project (pom.xml) - 
|-moduleA (no pom here)
|   |- it (pom.xml) - integration tests for "impl" module
|   |- impl (pom.xml) - implementaion + Unit tests
|-moduelB
|   |- it (pom.xml) - integration tests for "impl" module
|   |- impl (pom.xml) - implementaion + Unit tests
|-moduleC ...
```

I start build using following command:

```
mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent -Dmaven.compiler.debug=true install sonar:sonar
```

The problem is that Jacoco can easily support Unit test coverage inside the same module (so in my case Unit Tests inside `impl` module) but cannot analyze coverage from `it` module which itself does not contain any implementation classes. It just contains integration tests for `impl` module. It's clear for me why it doesn't work. I'm getting such info in Jacoco logs:

```
No JaCoCo analysis of project coverage can be done since there is no class files.
```

After I've defined `sonar.java.binaries` property inside moduleA/it/pom.xml like this:

```
    <properties>
         <sonar.java.binaries>../impl/target/classes</sonar.java.binaries>
    </properties>
```

coverage analysis of `it` still fails, but message in Jacoco logs changes to:

```
[INFO] Analysing D:\project\moduleA\it\target\jacoco.exec
[WARNING] Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?
```

I must mention that `D:\project\moduleA\it\target\jacoco.exec` file exists. I also checked that compiled classes in `D:\project\moduleA\impl\target\classes` contain debug data (all lines, vars and source).

I was trying with different paths inside `sonar.java.binaries` but result is always the same. I've tried:

```
../impl/target/classes
../../impl/target/classes
../../../impl/target/classes
../impl/target
...
```

**How can I configure Jacoco (Sonar) to allow it to find classes binaries in different maven sub module related to jacoco.exec file?**

Comment: Is there a reason why the integration tests are separate by the implemenation? The build configuration would be easier if you follow the Maven Pattern `src/main/java`for production code and `src/it/test` for integration test in the same module.

Comment: I am searching a solution to the same issue since several days with no luck!!!

Comment: @SandraParsick in my case it is because the code is spread across several Maven modules (API, Core, Web, etc.) and the IT module then runs a "full stack" test using Arquillian which starts a Wildfly application server. So coverage is to be tracked for the code base of several Maven modules.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699900), I resorted to the [Maven Ant plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) with [JaCoCo's ant task](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html) library, which allows richer inclusion trees:

```
<project ...>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>org.jacoco.ant</artifactId>
                        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
                        <version>20020829</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report-it-coverage</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals><goal>run</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${skipITs}</skip>
                            <target name="report-it-coverage">
                                <taskdef name="jacoco-report" classname="org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" />
                                <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" classpathref="maven.runtime.classpath" />
                                <available file="${jacoco.it-coverage.data}" property="jacoco.exec.file.exists" />
                                <if>
                                    <equals arg1="${jacoco.exec.file.exists}" arg2="true" />
                                    <then>
                                        <echo>Analyzing ITs coverage data from '${jacoco.it-coverage.data}'</echo>
                                        <jacoco-report>
                                            <executiondata>
                                                <file file="${jacoco.it-coverage.data}" />
                                            </executiondata>
                                            <structure name="ROOT">
                                                <classfiles>
                                                    <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/${project.parent.relativePath}">
                                                        <include name="**/target/classes/my/company/package/**/*.class" />
                                                        <exclude name="**/target/classes/my/test/glue/**/*" />
                                                    </fileset>
                                                </classfiles>
                                            </structure>
                                            <html destdir="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it" />
                                            <xml destfile="${project.build.directory}/jacoco.xml" />
                                        </jacoco-report>
                                    </then>
                                    <else>
                                        <echo>Missing ITs coverage data file '${jacoco.it-coverage.data}'</echo>
                                    </else>
                                </if>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```